# ежедневно в 6:33 теряется связь с DNS серверами на роутере с openwrt

Tags: dns, openwrt

логи естественно никакие не ведутся.

никаких заданий  нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

провайдер клянется что они там ничего не перезагружают

куда копать?

исправить ситуацию помогает реконект, но приходится его делать вручную каждый день!!!

вобщем порылся в планировщике задач винды, и нашел задание "Windows Defender Scheduled Scan"
оно заканчивает выполняется как раз в  6:33

если это и правда защитник виноват то как он может влиять на интернет на роутере???

Comment: перенесите задачу в планировщике на другое время. Если проблема перенесется также, значит это он виноват.

Comment: да я их вобще поотключал

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе, что именно вы подразумеваете под: а) «теряется связь» и б) «помогает реконнект».

Comment: похоже что это реально дефендер виноват. сегодня у меня интернет не отключался